# store procedure in trans sql vs pl sql

Tags: sql, t-sql, plsql, oracle11g, sql-server-2012

In oracle (pl-sql) I have

```
s as (select * from ruleassigns$all where [snapshot] = p_Id);
```

inside a stored procedure. I want to port it into sql server (trans-sql), but when I write the same it gives me error on the structure of the statement. Please help!
I am wondering something like

```
declare @s = (select * from ruleassigns$all where [snapshot] = p_Id);
```

but that's not correct either.

Comment: You have to declare @s with a datatype in one command and give it a value in another.

Comment: i know but what datatype should I take as this query is returning * (multiple values)

Comment: please past your *actual* Oracle code (ie include the preceding line(s) that are not terminated by ';')

Answer (score 0):

Since this query is returning multiple values you'd probably want to use a Declare @table.

The syntax will be

```
Declare @s Table (p_id SomeDataType(probably int?))
```

You can use @s just like any other table.

```
SELECT * FROM @s
```

`Note:` I personally like the feel of temporary tables. They feel like normal tables.

You'd write:

```
CREATE TABLE #tableName (p_id SomeDataType)
```

and at the end of your SP you'd do `DROP TABLE #tableName`